# how to groupby List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> in c#.net

Tags: c#, list, date, group-by

I have a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>>` and I filled this list with below data and I used below code to fill the list from a datatable
  code :

```
   dicArray = dtrd.AsEnumerable()
   .Select(Row => Row["IDp"]).Distinct()
   .Select(Id => new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>(
       Id.ToString(),
       dtrd.AsEnumerable()
           .Where(Row => Row["IDp"].ToString() == Id.ToString())
           .Select(Row => Row["date"].ToString())   
           .ToArray()))
   .ToList();
```

*data*

```
 1: 
    2017-2-1
    2017-2-1
    2017-2-1
    2017-2-2
    2017-2-2
    2017-2-2
   2:
    2017-4-1
    2017-4-1
   3:
    2017-3-1
    2017-3-1
```

now I want to groupby this list by date to generate this output

```
 1: 
    2017-2-1 count:3
    2017-2-2 count:3
   2:
    2017-4-1 count:2 
   3:
    2017-3-1 count:2
```

Comment: What is the key in the `KeyValuePair`?

Comment: key is ID; first item is key

Answer (score 3):

So you want to group by the ID and the Date? You first need `SelectMany` to flatten the arrays:

```
var query = list
     .SelectMany(kv => kv.Value.Select(s => new { Id = kv.Key, Date = s }))
     .GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Date })
     .Select(g => new { g.Key.Id, g.Key.Date, Count = g.Count() });
```

- `SelectMany` creates an anonymous type with two properties for every  string in all arrays.
- `GroupBy` creates one group for every `Id`+`Date` combination.
- The final `Select` adds the `Count` property.

---

According to your last comment:

```
var query = listKeyValue
 .SelectMany(kv => kv.Value
     .Select(arr => new
     {
         Id = kv.Key,
         Fields = arr.Split(';')
     }))
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.Id,
        Date = x.Fields[0],
        Number = x.Fields.Last()
    })
 .GroupBy(x => new { x.Date, x.Number })
 .Select(g => new { g.Key.Date, g.Key.Number, Count = g.Count() });
```

Comment: Dear Tim Schmelter : I cound not get the correct answer,for all items count is 1

Comment: Well, i've tried your code with this sample data: `List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> listKeyValue = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>>();
            listKeyValue.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>( "1", new string[] { "2017-2-1","2017-2-1","2017-2-1","2017-2-2","2017-2-2","2017-2-2"} ));` which i guess is more or less what OP has. Try it yourself

Comment: Now it works perfectly. I was trying to solve it also but I missed the `SelectMany` :)

Comment: @amin: what means persian date? You don't use `DateTime` but `String`, so it works with any string.

Comment: @amin: with `foreach`, or use any other way to materialize or display it. If you want to access it by index you can store it in a list or array: `var list = query.ToList();`

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter : how to group by List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> listKeyValue = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>>(); listKeyValue.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>( "1", new string[] { "2017-2-1;first","2017-2-1;first","2017-2-1;third","2017-2-2;second","2017-2-2;second","2017‌​-2-2;forth"} ));  By date and "first or second or third or ...."